# Can we get back the string passed in cout?

Tags: c++, string, cout

I have a code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World!";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

can i get back the string "Hello World!" in some char or string variable ?

Comment: Why don't you just put it in a variable before writing it to cout?

Comment: @Barmar What if you want the whole output screen in a variable ? you cannot concatenate every string variable in one btw i was just exploring.

Comment: @user3284775 Cannot concatenate every string variable?  Sure you can ... It is not all that useful, but there is nothing stopping you from doing it.

Comment: @ Zac Howland yeah i know but at professional level every non-useful thing is waste of time and the concatenation part would make code big instead you can add 3-4 lines and get the result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you can use string streams to achieve that effect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;

oss << "Hello World!";

std::cout << oss.str();
```

Now `oss.str()` still contains the string you built.

Comment: this is a nice way but not the desired answer here also you made a variable,passed "Hello World!" and then used that variable in std::cout

Comment: @user3284775: The strict answer to the question is "No", the rest shows the next-best solution that is almost a drop-in replacement.